# Datatable table.fnUpdate firing an action twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, datatables

I am implementing datatable in server-side processing,
In controller(ROR), I am having an action

```
def search_result
  render json: ExampleDatatable.new(view_context)
end
```

now from js I am initialising it

```
var table = $("#example_list").DataTable({

    iDisplayLength: 10,
    bSort: true,
    bPaginate: true,
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    //bFilter: false,
    bStateSave: true,
    bRetrieve: true,
    bDestroy: true,
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: true,
    sAjaxSource: '/example/search__result'
});
```

And I am getting the result here.
But I need to update the table according to the custom search(input from form in a view).
now ..

```
var new_table = $("#token_list").DataTable();
$(document).on("submit", "#example_form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var key1 = $("#_xyz").val();
    var key2 = $("#_abc").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/example/search_result',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: false,
        data:{
            "xyz": key1,
            "abc": key2

        },
        success: function (data) {
            for(i=0; i < data.aaData.length; i++){
                table.fnUpdate( data.aaData[i], i );
            }
            return false;

        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            console.log("Error in sending the data");
        }
    });
});
```

In success of the ajax call I am getting the searched data but I think on fnUpdate search_result is firing twice..and the updated data will be removed by the old data. 
But I need the updated data.not the old one.

Comment: This issue is solved now, I just need to add fnServerParams: function (aoData) {
            aoData.push(
                { "name": "_name", "value":"some value" 
            );
        },